# gvfs-mount won't mount a ssh host specified in config

Tags: ssh, mount, thunar, gvfs

I am struggling with configuring gvfs-mount to work with a host that is being connected to through a proxy. My config looks like this:

```
Host proxyhost
  User [username]
  HostName [domain]
  Port [non-standard port]

Host destination
  HostName [ip]
  User [other username]
  Port 22
  IdentityFile [path to private key]
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh proxyhost nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

I am able to connect to it through the terminal - `ssh destination` works perfectly fine. The first server just asks for password and I'm logged in.

But when I try to connect through gvfs-mount (I would like to work using Thunar) it prompts for username and password and I have completely no idea what should I provide there. I tried credentials to the proxyhost and it does not work. I just keep being asked 3 times for passoword and then returned

```
Error mounting location: Permission denied
```

error. Is there any way that I can make it work?